# VB.net getting tag info into mp3 files

Tags: mediaelement

How can I get internal info about sound files using a `MediaElement`?

I know how to get the duration of a song file with `NaturalDuration` property but I want to get access to `Author` and others tag that many mp3 files include into themselves. Is there some way to do this using just `MediaElement`? I know how to do it but only with WMP and I really need to do it just with a `MediaElement` because my application is a UWP application.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, late and may be not so elegant but this was my solution for getting duration of a mp3 file. I used MusicProperties Class. With this class you get access for any music tag information into the file.

Public Function infoMP3(elfichero As String) As String

```
Dim salida As String = ""
Dim miTask = Task.Run(Async Function() As Task(Of String)
                          Dim musicFile As StorageFile = Await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(elfichero)
                          Dim FileProperties As StorageItemContentProperties = musicFile.Properties
                          Dim musicFileProperties As MusicProperties = Await FileProperties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync()
                          Dim tiempo = musicFileProperties.Duration
                          Dim horas As String
                          If tiempo.Hours < 10 Then
                              horas = "0" & tiempo.Hours.ToString
                          Else
                              horas = tiempo.Hours.ToString
                          End If
                          Dim minutos As String
                          If tiempo.Minutes < 10 Then
                              minutos = "0" & tiempo.Minutes.ToString
                          Else
                              minutos = tiempo.Minutes.ToString
                          End If
                          Dim segundos As String
                          If tiempo.Seconds < 10 Then
                              segundos = "0" & tiempo.Seconds.ToString
                          Else
                              segundos = tiempo.Seconds.ToString
                          End If
                          Dim autor = musicFileProperties.Artist
                          Dim titulo = musicFileProperties.Title

                          Dim presalida As String = "[" & horas & ":" & minutos & ":" & segundos & "];[" & titulo & "];[" & autor & "]    " & elfichero
                          Return presalida
                      End Function)
miTask.Wait()
salida = miTask.Result
Return salida
```

End Function
To get access to the files later on Windows 10, you have to save permission for the files and/or folders. Do this when you select them.

... Dim listToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(rutaS) ...

where rutaS is an SotorageFolder object.